# Google Apps Script - Use utilities class

Tags: google-apps-script

I am just learning the apps script for Google Apps and I see lots of references to the Utilities and Math Classes. How do I go about adding these classes to my script. When I try to reference methods an error appears.

Code I have tried:

```
function myTest() { 
    var name = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString(); 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var sht_0 = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
    var sht_1 = ss.insertSheet(name); 
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sht_0); 
    utilities.sleep(10000); 
    var rng = sht_0.setActiveRange('A1:A5'); 
    sht_0.setActiveRange(rng); 
}
```

The Error I get:

> ReferenceError: "utilities" is not defined. (line 7, file "Code")

Thanks 
Ian

Comment: please provide us with the code you tried and the errors you get so we can help you more precisely.

Comment: Here is my code...

'function myTest() {
  var name = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString();  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht_0 = ss.getActiveSheet();    
  var sht_1 = ss.insertSheet(name);    
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sht_0);    
  utilities.sleep(10000);  
  var rng = sht_0.setActiveRange('A1:A5');  
  sht_0.setActiveRange(rng);  
}'

The error is...
ReferenceError: "utilities" is not defined. (line 7, file "Code")

How do I format the code better?

Comment: Utilities takes a capital first letter. Use the autocomplete feature to avoid these problems ( control + space).

Comment: As with many languages, case is important